# hour() and date() functions are returning wrong values

Tags: datetime, date, timezone, locale

I am trying to get the hour and date of the user's local timezone by using the below code.

```
now = Datetime.now();
offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
local = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);
hourNow = local.hour();
todayDate = local.date();
```

For example, my timezone is IST, and hence the third line of the code, that is the DateTime variable **local** has the following value `2021-07-05 21:00:20`

But when I try to get the hour and date values from the variable **local** using the hour() and date() function on the 4th and 5th lines I am receiving the wrong values.

For `hour()` that is variable **hourNow** I am receiving **2** instead of **21**, and for `date()` that is variable **todayDate** I am receiving **2021-07-06 00:00:00** instead of **2021-07-05 00:00:00**

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong here, and why am I receiving these wrong values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.hour()` and `.date()` functions show time in user local time zone already, so you do not need to add offset to `now` variable.

```
now = Datetime.now();
hourNow = now.hour();
todayDate = now.date();
```

Comment: That worked, I wasn't aware of this! thank you!